# Add content of static block as new tab to product detail page

Tags: layout, template, static-block

I created 3 static blocks with just a random headline for now, where I want to add html content later.
the ids of the blocks are:

```
warranty
instructions
certificates
```

I then created 3 .phtml files with content like this ( will jsut add one because they all look the same):

```
<?php

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('warranty')->toHtml();
```

I placed all the three files in `app/design/frontend/rwd/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view`

so I have these files lying there:

```
warranty.phtml
instructions.phtml
certificates.phtml
```

Then I added this in `app/design/frontend/rwd/mytheme/layout/local.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/template" name="product.warranty" as="warranty" template="catalog/product/view/warranty.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Garantie</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template" name="product.instructions" as="instructions" template="catalog/product/view/instructions.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Anleitung</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template" name="product.certificates" as="certificates" template="catalog/product/view/certificates.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Zertifikate</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

It doesn't work.
Nothing showing up on the product pages.
There are only the 3 tabs that have already been there before including one that seems to have been added the same way I just tried: (same code in .xml adding blocks to the detailed_info group and linking to a template.phtml file which is then using the same code as I do to call the static block.
But I must be missing some step in between because for me it doesn't work.
What am I missing?

Edit: The part of the `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` where the output of the detailed_info group happens looks like this:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by following way, please check & i have tested it.

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <reference name="product.info">
                <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes1" as="additional1" template="catalog/product/view/warranty.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Garantie</value></action>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes2" as="additional2" template="catalog/product/view/instructions.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Anleitung</value></action>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes3" as="additional3" template="catalog/product/view/certificates.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Zertifikate</value></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Oh I see, that happens when you just ctrl-v like that.
I tried your code though and it still doesn't work.
Anything else I might have missed?

Comment: i have updated my answer, please check.
local.xml file will start with <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0"> and end with 
</layout>

Comment: Unfortunately this stil doesn't work

Comment: For checking , trying to add static HTML into the phtml file. Only xml file is required & once update clear cache and check